# Faut-il dire « projet tutoré » ou « projet tuteuré » ?

Tags: usage, science, université

J'utilise « projet tuteuré » (provient du tuteur). Aujourd'hui mes collègues m'ont dit qu'il faut employer « projet tutoré ». Cependant mon éditeur de texte ne reconnait pas ce dernier terme. Il a plutôt l'air d'être un anglicisme (tutor). Cherchant sur Internet, on constate que « projet tutoré » est plus répandu que « projet tuteuré ». Mais je ne vois pas un consensus sur l'emploi établi. Alors, quelle forme doit-on employer ?

Comment: Ça ressemble à un calque de l'anglais (_mentored project_), sais-tu c'est quoi la différence entre le _projet tutoré_ et le _travail d'équipe supervisé_ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selon l’OQLF [***Tuteurer***](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=10449348) est un terme d’horticulture, vraisemblablement *« munir d’un [tuteur](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8972623) »*, le tuteur étant une...

> Armature rigide destinée à soutenir ou à redresser une plante.

Selon la même source...

> [***Tutorer***](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26512042)   Accompagner un élève ou un étudiant éprouvant des difficultés en lui offrant une aide pédagogique personnalisée.

Pour le changement du groupe de lettres -eu- en -o-, notons que ce n’est pas un cas unique en français, même s’il s’applique plus généralement à des noms, parmi lesquels on retrouve l’état du tuteur *(le tutorat)*, ainsi que d’autres termes utilisant le même suffixe [-at](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/-at) :

- tut**eu**r / tut**o**rat
- profess**eu**r / profess**o**rat
- élect**eu**r / élect**o**rat
- protect**eu**r / protect**o**rat
- cens**eu**r / cens**o**rat
- past**eu**r / past**o**rat

La plupart de ces état ne se transforment pas en verbes, ce qui confère un caractère un peu unique au tutorat, qui a engendré **tutorer.** Il est vrai que °tuter ne paierait pas de mine...

Comment: Cependant, je me demande pourquoi le mot tutorer n'est pas reconnu par les éditeurs de texte. (Merci pour la réponse by the way:-)!).

Comment: @Dimitris Chaque éditeur de texte choisit les mots qu’il inclura, avec possibilité de personnaliser son dictionnaire pour certains éditeurs. Des termes spécialisés et rares en abondance pourraient, je spécule, ralentir la performance et parfois même ne pas corriger certaines saisies à cause d’un terme rare qui collerait à notre entrée.

Comment: C'est noté. Donc le mot existe en français et n'est pas un anglicisme. Merci encore.

Answer (score 3):

Le verbe tuteurer existe bien puisque il se trouve dans [le Larousse en ligne](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/tuteurer/80322); cependant sa signification n'a rien à voir avec l'enseignement;

> (Larousse en ligne) tuteurer : Munir d'un tuteur un jeune arbre, une plante

[L'internaute](https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/tutorer/)
confirme les dires de vos collègues.

> tutorer , verbe transitif 
>   Le verbe tutorer est utilisé pour désigner le tutorat d'un élève qu'assure un professeur. Tutorer un élève revient à l'aider dans ses devoirs, à lui apporter une aide personnalisée en fonction de ses besoins.

Tout indique qu'il faut utiliser la forme « tutorer ».

Comment: Cependant le mot tutoré ne fait pas partie de Larousse:-)! https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/rechercher?q=tutor%C3%A9&l=francais&culture=

Comment: https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/rechercher?q=tutorer&l=francais&culture=

Comment: @Dimitris il n'y a pas d'adjectif; mais que l'on veuille un adjectif correspondant au verbe et il est très peu probable que l'on n'utilise pas le participe passé comme adjectif (les participes passés ne sont pas listés dans le Larousse et d'autres dictionnaires).